# Grub2 broken after editing grub.cfg

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, dell, dell-vostro

In attempting to update the bios on my machine so that it would allow me to utilize all of the installed RAM, I found instructions on adding the option to the GRUB bootloader menu.  Since the only bios update was a Windows exe file, I followed more instruction on how to convert it and make it usable By Linux. Inside of grub.cfg in the #40 area where you would add the extra menu items, I added exactly per the instructions three lines, and saved the file.  How? I don't know, but in never booted again.  I feel as if I could remove those three lines, the system would boot again, and all would be well. Using USB installer, I ran 16.04 on the machine, found the volume and the .cfg file, but it WILL NOT allow me to save the edited file... Can anyone tell me how to go about this the proper way?  I have researched and looked all over the place, to no avail...

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you know what to edit in the file and you are just stuck at saving your edits, I feel you should use `sudo`

E.g.: `sudo nano /xyz/xyz.cfg` and then try saving using `Ctrl+X`